# Android 4.0.4 Where to Download su or sudo Binary?

Tags: rooting, root-access, shell, terminal

I have a Huawei Android 4.0.4 phone and I've recently downloaded a Terminal Emulator app. This app allows me to run a Linux shell from inside Android; it runs `/system/bin/sh`. I started to navigate around the OS and I've found that `/system/xbin` only has `DisableLoopTest`, `EnableLoopTest`, `dexdump`, and `hciutils_test` in it. `/system/bin` has many files; I believe that all of the installed commands are in it. However, I noticed that `su` and `sudo` where not in `/system/bin` or `/system/xbin`. Where can I download this file or some other file to root my Android device?

Comment: You need to search for a specific guide to root your device, just adding the binaries won't help (you can't add them anyways, because `/system` is write protected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was correctly stated by the [GiantTree](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/86358/gianttree), adding `su` binaries won't help you much as you do not have root. After rooting they more than likely will be added by default.

What concerns adding missing commands to Andorid shell, then you'd better not to do that one by one, bur rather install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en). It contains a big set of predefined commands.